# Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketTimeoutException & Non HTTP response message: Read timed out

Tags: jmeter

I am getting below error while executing script on Jmeter how can we resolve  this issue. . please help me

Status Code : Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketTimeoutException    & Non HTTP response message: Read timed out
Status Code : 504 Gateway Time-out
Status Code : 502 Gateway Time-out

Comment: actually i am getting this error while increase time limit timeouts limit  100000 second & getting   Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLException
Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException

Answer (score 0):

1. [HTTP Status Code 502](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502)

   > The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 502 Bad Gateway server error response code indicates that the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, **received an invalid response from the upstream server**.
2. [HTTP Status Code 504](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/504)

   > The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 504 Gateway Timeout server error response code indicates that the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, **did not get a response in time from the upstream server** that it needed in order to complete the request. In other words, your web servers aren't communicating with each other fast enough.

There is nothing you can do from JMeter side because both error messages indicate that the server is overloaded and either responds incorrectly or doesn't respond at all.

The only recommendations I can provide are:

1. Start with 1 virtual user and [gradually increase the load](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide/) until the errors start occurring. Look at [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener to see how many virtual users were online by that time - most probably this is absolute maximum which your current setup can support
2. Inspect your application logs, most probably the root cause of the problem is there
3. Consider monitoring your application health metrics (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc.) using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) as it might be simply lack of resources